# To get logs in between particular time-stamps along with date using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract infromation from logs using a shell script for a particular time range . A line in logs looks like this:

`[15:01:27:176][15-10-2015]: testing1-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:02:27:178][15-10-2015]: testing2-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:10:27:179][15-10-2015]: testing3-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:01:27:180][16-10-2015]: testing4-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:20:27:181][16-10-2015]: testing5-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:02:27:182][16-10-2015]: testing6-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:03:27:183][17-10-2015]: testing7-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:04:27:184][17-10-2015]: testing8-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:05:27:191][17-10-2015]: testing9-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:18:27:192][17-10-2015]: testing10-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:29:27:193][17-10-2015]: testing11-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:03:27:208][18-10-2015]: testing12-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:04:27:209][18-10-2015]: testing13-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:07:27:210][18-10-2015]: testing14-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015`

I need to extract data in specific intervals. for example in between 15:01 to 15:08 on [17-10-2015] date

> [15:03:27:183][17-10-2015]: testing7-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
>   [15:04:27:184][17-10-2015]: testing8-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
>   [15:05:27:191][17-10-2015]: testing9-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015

I used this code :

```
grep -E "^[(15:0[1-8])" | grep '[17-10' filename
```

I tried this . I am getting all 17-10-2015 data including 15:18 &15:29.
I need only data from 15:01 to 15:08. Is it correct , anythting wrong in this ?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me :

```
grep "\[17-10" filename | grep  "15:0[1-8]"
```